# IE Alternative to Column-Count & Column-Gap

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am wondering if there is an IE alternative to using `column-count` and `column-gap`?

I have made this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305389/auto-create-columns-using-single-plain-list) about creating a list that automatically create a new column for every fifth element. Leniel has suggested a solution that uses `column-count` and `column-gap` but this is not supported by IE. I am looking for a fall back solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this: [Multi-column Layout with CSS3](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/a/css3-multi-columns.htm). Read the section titled *CSS3 Multi-Column Browser Support*. It states the following:

> If you need to support browsers that don't have multi-column support,
>   then you should have a fallback option for those browsers. Here is how
>   you can do it with the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) script...

1. Place the following SCRIPT tag in your HEAD after any other style sheets:

   ```
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.0.6/modernizr.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add another SCRIPT below the above line that reads:

   ```
   <script>
   Modernizr.load({
     test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
     yep: 'columns.css',
     nope: 'no-columns.css'
   });
   </script>
   ```
3. Create a CSS style sheet that includes your multi-columns CSS and save it as columns.css in the same directory.
4. Create a CSS style sheet that contains your fallback CSS (such as columns with float) and save it as no-columns.css in the same directory.
   Test your page in IE and Chrome, Safari, or Opera.

---

The page [Multiple Columns](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/) provides a JavaScript fallback if you're interested going this way.

Comment: I prefer not to use javascript to detect internet explorer, I use conditional comments:

`<body>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><div id=ie-9-or-older"><![endif]-->
    <div id="page">Your html code here...</div>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]></div><![endif]-->
</body>`

In your css, you can make selectors like this:

`#ie-9-or-older #page{
    /*some css for your ie*/
}`

Comment: If you prefer to use jquery.columnizer.js, here's a nice Modernizer script snippet. https://gist.github.com/jimmynotjim/3666470

Answer (score 4):

Here is solution how to make menu with multicolumns which looks the same as the one created with column-count property and works in **ALL BROWSERS**.

This is done with floating elements, but the trick here is to re-order the elements in javascript (or server side) so they **natural flow looks as up-down instead left-right**

***Item1  Item4  Item7***

***Item2  Item5  Item8***

***Item3  Item6***

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xrd5Y/16/

```
// number of columns
var columns = 4;

var $ul = $('ul.multicolumn'),
    $elements = $ul.children('li'),
    breakPoint = Math.ceil($elements.length/columns);
    $ordered = $('<div></div>');

function appendToUL(i) {
    if ($ul.children().eq(i).length > 0) {
        $ordered.append($ul.children().eq(i).clone());
    } 
    else $ordered.append($('<li></li>'));
}

function reorder($el) {
    $el.each(function(){
        $item = $(this);

        if ($item.index() >= breakPoint) return false;

        appendToUL($item.index());
        for (var i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
            appendToUL(breakPoint*i+$item.index());
        }
    });

    $ul.html($ordered.children().css('width',100/columns+'%'));
}

reorder($elements);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works for me: Rather than using JS or a IE-only conditional you can use Modernizr's classes directly in your stylesheet.

If you do an Inspect Element on our webpage, you will see that there are many CSS classes added in the html tag:

[image: If you do an Inspect Element on our webpage, you will see that there are many CSS classes added to the html tag]

If the user's browser does not support css columns you will see a "no-csscolumns" class that you can use to float elements.

Comment: Note: you won't see Modernizr generated `CSS` classes in the Browser's view source code. Use `Firebug` for Firefox as shown in the screenshot above or some other DOM viewer... :) Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835579/114029

Answer (score -2):

Here is simple solution I discovered for IE and IE Edge just separate each column by paragraph `<p> your text </p>`, column-2 `<p> your text </p>`, it worked for me.

```
#subfootera {
    with:100%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;

}

.subfooterb {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 10px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 10px;
}

  <div id="subfootera">
    <div class="subfooterb">
    <p>Your Text.</p>
    <p>Your text or an img</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```