# Split large list into three equal height lists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a bit of advice on this javascript (jQuery) issue (I'm not a frontend dev, so please bear with me ;-))

I have one large `<ul>` that I need to split in three separate `<ul>`s with an equal number of menuitems in each. So if I have five `<li>`s in my large `<ul>`, it will look like this:

```
Listitem 1           Listitem 3         Listitem5
ListItem 2           Listitem 4
```

etc.

Is there any way of doing this in javascript/jQuery? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not CSS and have a div: `div
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Css is always best for this however if you have to be backwards compatible or need it to be in separate lists for some other reason. I have knocked up a quick script for this. It could probably be a bit optimized as I just threw it together but does what you need.

I stuck it up on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/whAyt/8/ hope it helps

```
function breakList(numOfLists, list){
    var listLength = list.find("li").size();
    var numInRow = Math.ceil(listLength / numOfLists);
    for (var i=0;i<numOfLists;i++){
        var listItems = list.find("li").slice(0, numInRow);
        var newList = $('<ul/>').append(listItems);
        $("body").append(newList);
    }
}

breakList(3, $(".list"));
```

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks for a great answer :-) I tried tinkering around with your code and it works fine. Although, if there's an odd number of list items, it seems to miscalculate it. Check this updated jsfiddle where I have removed the last list item: http://jsfiddle.net/whAyt/6/

Comment: Changed Math.round() to Math.ceil() and used "float: left;" instead of "display:inline-block"; :-) Works like a charm!

Comment: Good shout @bomortensen like I said this was just a quick nock up example I have updated with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

How about CSS and a div?

```
div {
  -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count:3;
}
```

More here

[IE Alternative to Column-Count & Column-Gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306188/ie-alternative-to-column-count-column-gap)

Comment: thanks mpungjan, greatly appreciated :-) I like the css3 solution, but optimizing for <IE9 is a pain though :-( Would rather go with one-off javascript solution to be honest

Answer (score -1):

Still css only :

```
#theList { width: 100% }

#theList li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3B7a/)

You would have to produce your `<li>` nodes in the correct order if you want to have them ordered by column.