# wpf webview html page splitter

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer

### wpf webview html page splitter

I am doing a eReader application in wpf.I have to display html content as pages.Using the following style I can split html content into columns in webkitBrowsers.

```
   "var jsPagenate = "function a() {"
                + "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];"
                + "var ourH = window.innerHeight; "
                + "var ourW = window.innerWidth; " + "var fullH = this.clientHeight; "
                + "var pageCount = Math.floor(fullH/ourH)+1;"
                + "var currentPage = 0; " + "var newW = pageCount*ourW; "
                + "d.style.height = ourH+'px';" + "d.style.width = newW+'px';"
                + "d.style.webkitColumnGap = '0px'; " + "d.style.margin = 0; "
                + "d.style.webkitColumnCount = pageCount;}";"
```

But it is not working in wpf webbrowsers.

How can I implement in IE?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.any help?

Comment: @Sachin123, can you first make it work in full IE browser, before taking it to the WPF `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: @Noseratio How to make it work in full IE browser?

Comment: @ARUNRAJ, that's a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306188/ie-alternative-to-column-count-column-gap