# How to fix CSS3 column-count for IE?

Tags: css

I am searching for a fix, so the CSS property `column-count` works also in IE 9 and lower.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE Alternative to Column-Count & Column-Gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306188/ie-alternative-to-column-count-column-gap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-column layout is not supported by Internet Explorer, even version 9. However, current versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera all handle CSS3 multi-column layout without a problem.

If you need to support browsers that don't have multi-column support, then you should have a fallback option for those browsers. Here is how you can do it with the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) script

Place the following SCRIPT tag in your HEAD after any other style sheets:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.0.6/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

Add another SCRIPT below the above line that reads:

```
<script>
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
  yep: 'columns.css',
  nope: 'no-columns.css'
});
</script>
```

Create a CSS style sheet that includes your multi-columns CSS and save it as columns.css in the same directory.

Create a CSS style sheet that contains your fallback CSS (such as [columns with float](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/ss/css_layout_sbs.htm)) and save it as no-columns.css in the same directory.

I found a article on this: [Read this](http://pterkildsen.com/2012/12/08/css3-columns-in-internet-explorer-7-8-and-9/)

and here already a answer available for that : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306188/ie-alternative-to-column-count-column-gap)