# CSS Mansory showing more columns than the set amount

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS Masonry I'm having problems it's showing 5 columns in a row instead of 4 which is what I have set. This is the css code I used:

```
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 3px; 
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 3px; 
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 3px; 
column-fill: auto;
```

Live site can be viewed here http://www.littlebusters.nu/ anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What browser are you using?  It looks correct in chrome but wrong in IE and firefox.  Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306188/ie-alternative-to-column-count-column-gap

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I see 5 images in a row